# Error when enable dataBidning in android studio 2022.3.1

Tags: android-studio, data-binding

I'm still new with Android Studio, and am just trying to enable dataBinding with this code,

```
dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
```

and got error message **Unresolved reference: enabled**

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iI9iz.png)

My complete gradle file content is below

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
    id("kotlin-android")
}

android {

    namespace = "com.example.apitest"
    compileSdk = 33
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.apitest"
        minSdk = 24
        targetSdk = 33
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }

    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.10.1")
    implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.9.1")
    implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1")
    implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0")
    implementation("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
}
```

Does anyone know what is the issue? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace

```
    dataBinding {
    enabled = true
}
```

with

```
buildFeatures {
    viewBinding true
    dataBinding true
}
```